# Equality between a list as a sub element of a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having a weird problem that I can't fix. I've created a Numpy array named `arr`:

```py
import numpy as np

v1 = 1
e1 = [1, 2]
arr1 = [v1, e1] # Numpy array's first element

v2 = 2
e2 = [3, 5]
arr2 = [v2, e2] # Numpy array's second element

arr = np.array([arr1, arr2]) # My Numpy array
# array([[1, list([1, 2])],
#        [2, list([3, 5])]], dtype=object)
```

I want to find the position(s) of the list `[3, 5]` in the array `arr` (of course, by taking into account the placement of the `list` object in the latter [2nd column of each line]). So, I tried this command:

```py
arr[:, 1] == [3, 5]
# array([False, False])
```

However, I am supposed to get: `array([False, True])` (The list `[3, 5]` exists in the second line of `arr`).

To verify, I've tried to test the equality manually. Everything is ok, I've got expected results:

```py
arr[:, 1][0] == [3, 5] # False
arr[:, 1][1] == [3, 5] # True
```

So, why by using the equality between `arr` and `[3, 5]` I've got `array([False, False])` instead of `array([False, True])`?

Comment: The duplicate is rather dated (2013), but in general working with object dtype arrays is not as straight forward as working with numeric ones.  In one way or other `numpy` has to 'fudge', iterating on the elements, delegating the comparison to the elements, etc.  Other than being able index with `arr[:,i]`, this array has few, if any, advantages relative to the list `[arr1, arr2]`.

Comment: I think `arr[:,1]==[3,5]` is actually doing `arr[:,1]==np.array([3,5])`, with all the array broadcasting rules.   To do the test you want you have to construct or extract a 1 element object array containing the list `[3,5]`, e.g. `arr[:,1] == np.array(arr2)[[1]] `

Comment: @yatu, I don't think this is a `contains` issue.  It's more how `numpy` does an `==` test between two arrays.  It isn't doing a simple list equality test.

Comment: True, reopened @hpaulj . Indeed it seems that each element in the list gets broadcasted across `arr`.  Testing with `arr==(1,[1,2])` produces True for both elements in the first row, whereas `arr==[1,2]` only for the first element

Answer (score 1):

I think `arr[:,1]==[3,5]` is actually doing `arr[:,1]==np.array([3,5])`, with all the array broadcasting rules.

To do the test you want you have to construct or extract a 1 element object array containing the list `[3,5]`, e.g.

```
arr[:,1] == np.array(arr2)[[1]]
```